# Deprecation in 'navigationOptions': - 'headerLeft: <SomeElement />' will be removed in a future version. Use 'headerLeft: () => <SomeElement />'

Tags: react-native

```
HomeScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
    return{
        headerTitle: 'Title'.toUpperCase(),
        headerLeft: (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                <Item title="Menu" iconName="menu" onPress={() => {
                    navData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
                }} />
            </HeaderButtons>
        )
    };
}
```

This is my code, when I run the project it shows me a warning message:
Deprecation in 'navigationOptions': - 'headerLeft: ' will be removed in a future version. Use 'headerLeft: () => '

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wrap your headerLeft value in a function.

```
headerLeft: () => (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                <Item title="Menu" iconName="menu" onPress={() => {
                    navData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
                }} />
            </HeaderButtons>
        )
```